# How to ctrl drag object from view into code when code is opened in separate window?

Tags: xcode

I'm trying to use Xcode for the first time and have run into an issue. I've read to add event handlers for objects, you ctrl+drag them from the view into the code.

The problem is that in Xcode 7, the code is shown in a different window than the view. When I try ctrl+dragging the object, there is no way as far as I can tell to get it into the code window. I tried pressing ctrl+` to open the code window, but it doesn't work while ctrl+dragging.

Video: http://www.screencast.com/t/0z2IuuTXaB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep the Interface Builder view open and open also the Assistant Editor (click on two circle symbol on right top or press <kbd>⌥⌘↩</kbd> ).

PS: I recommend to watch the WWDC videos "What's new in Xcode" of the last 2 or 3 years